# What do we do with questions that are PEBCAK

Tags: discussion

I see a bunch of questions where "Problem Exists Between Chair And Keyboard", and the user figures this out.

Do we close as *too localized* ?

Example: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/110517/showing-only-one-category-on-homepage

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes.

An exception could be made for very common errors or hidden traps in WordPress’ core code which deserve a good explanation.